# How to use Settings.py file if it is in local directory

Tags: python, django

I  have a Django project, let's say "project1". Typical folder structure for applications is:

```
/project1/
    /project1/
        /settings.py
        /urls.py
        /wsgi.py
    /manage.py
```

Now I want to move this settings.py file into local directory. Then how to use this setting.py file in our project (What should i write in manage.py and wsgi.py for use of settings.py file from new moved local directory location)

Comment: What do you mean by local directory ? And what is need of it ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your local directory into your Python path (don't forget to put a `__init__.py` file in the local folder) and adapt your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, which is defined in the `manage.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")
```

Be aware that it will take the first `yourproject.settings` found in your Python Path, so it is not really a good idea to move it from the folder project. You can also use the [`--settings` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings) to specify the file to use.

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=yourproject.settings
```

---

Be careful, if you are doing this to avoid to commit the settings on a SVN/Git/Hg repository, it might be way easier to ignore the file in your CVS configuration, by ignoring `settings.py` (and `*.pyc`)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in django.wsgi

if you are using django with apache and mod_wsgi, have a look at 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/